# How to sort the query results by the creating order(SL number)?

Tags: aem, query-builder

Is there a way to query AEM to get results in the order of node creation. I want to sort based on the current order of nodes in siteadmin/DAM (not the node creation date).

Answer (score 0):

you can use sql2 'order by' clause

go to crxde and then click on `tool`. Select `SQL2` and give your path in `path` and write

`SELECT * FROM [dam:Asset] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/content/dam]) order by [jcr:created]`

May this help..:)